# Zend framework: Execute code after response sent to user

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a simple requirement to execute some code after the view has rendered and been sent back to the user.

The user does not need to be notified of the results of the processing and I do not want to hold up the user while processing something that is not relevant to them, even though it will only probably take a few seconds extra.

I know for some heavy lifting I should probably implement gearman or something similar, but just need something quick and simple for the moment.

I do ideally still need access to the zend_registry and other data created in the executed action.

I was thinking plugin and trapping routeShutdown() but this seems to far gone already...

What thoughts...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In a circumstance like this, I usually create a queue - probably stored in a db table - and then run a cron process to consume the queue. The queue contains the data - or at least pointers to the data - that I need to do the post-request processing.

**Note:** The actual HTTP request object and all request-specific data (like anything stored in the Zend_Registry) are **gone**, **not** directly accessible by your cron process. If you need any of that per-request data to do your post-request processing, then make sure you store that data in your work queue or in some other persistent place.

Comment: I think this is the most optimal solution for OP. No need to install message queue daemons and could be implemented relatively fast.